# onDataChange() return me values twice

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with my code. I've tried all the day to resolve this code but I can't, I don't know how to do it. The problem is that onDataChange() returns me duplicate values. I've tried to add this line "addListenerForSingleValueEvent()" and also to disable the Offline Persistence of Firebase by writting "FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);" but it didn't work. I end up getting duplicates values (see image below).
[Duplicates values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcT3m.png)

My code for retrieving the data from Firebase is:

```
    @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Course>().setQuery(reference, Course.class).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Course, CourseViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CourseViewHolder courseViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Course course) {
            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String course_name = ds.child("Course name").getValue().toString();
                        courseViewHolder.courseRealName.setText(course_name);
                        Log.d(TAG, course_name);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CourseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.create_course_view,parent, false);
            CourseViewHolder viewHolder = new CourseViewHolder(v);
            return  viewHolder;
        }
    };
    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

RecyclerView code

```
            @NonNull
        @Override
        public CourseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.create_course_view,parent, false);
            CourseViewHolder viewHolder = new CourseViewHolder(v);
            return  viewHolder;
        }
    };
    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public static class CourseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView courseName, courseRealName,numberOfStudent, realNumberOfStudents;

    public CourseViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        courseName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.denCursList);
        courseRealName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.realCourseName);
        numberOfStudent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.numarStudentiInfo);
        realNumberOfStudents = itemView.findViewById(R.id.numarRealStudenti);
    }
}
```

I'm waiting for a response. Thank you!

Comment: use the `course` object as data source instead of implementing `reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent `

Comment: I've tried, but it returns me nothing on RecyclerView

Comment: then the issue is in your query setup with `adapter`

Comment: add a screen shot for database, and add the code for the database reference, and the code where you set the recyclerview.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam I have uploaded a screenshot with my Firebase Database.

Comment: where is the code for setting the recyclerview, and the code where you make the databse reference.

Comment: Done. I've modified the post!

Comment: Okay add also this class `Course .java`

Comment: @HasanBouTaam Done! I have modified the post and added Course.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Okay The class must be like this:**

```
public class Course{

//these must be exactly same as the database naming, and the same fields

private String CourseID;
private String Coursedescription;
private String Coursename;
private int Coursepoints;
private int Coursestudents;
private String TeacherID;


//constructor

public Course(String CourseID, String Coursedescription, String Coursename,int Coursepoints , int Coursestudents, String TeacherID) {
    this.CourseID = CourseID;
    this.Coursedescription = Coursedescription;
    this.Coursename = Coursename;
    this.Coursepoints = Coursepoints;
    this.Coursestudents = Coursestudents;
    this.TeacherID = TeacherID;
}



//generate getters and setters..........

}
```

**And in `onBindViewHolder()` no need for the listener:**

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Course, CourseViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CourseViewHolder courseViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Course course) {


     //set directly
     courseViewHolder.courseRealName.setText(course.getCoursename());




}
```

Comment: The spacing, upper case, lower case must be the exact same in your class `Course ` and in the `database`.

Comment: The class must have code like private String Course ID or it's just private String ID? Or I have to write the lines another else?

Comment: You must rewrite the class, to make the fields the exact same as the ones in the database.

Comment: If its written in the database `Course ID` it must be in the class `Course ID`

Comment: in my answer I showed you which ones must be `Strings` and which ones must be `ints`

Comment: Ah okay, probably it was a "_" between Course and ID in the code of Course.java that you've posted. I'm getting it. I will modify the code that refers to adding in Firebase data. Probably it needs a "_" between Course and ID.

Comment: In your database I don't see "_" I see space, so in your class it must be space between them.

Comment: yes there shouldn't be spaces between the names (my bad), but in your database also there must be no sapces ......do you get what I mean.....They must be exactly the same.

Comment: It works. I've modified the variables in Firebase. Thank you so much for help!

Comment: Great if this was helpful accept the answer so others with same problem know where to look.

Comment: Done! Thank you again for help!